# Electric conductivity vs potential

Tags: conductivity, electricity

What is the relationship between electric potential and conductivity?

For example, gold has a more negative electric potential than silver (-1.100 vs -0.800), but silver is a better conductor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not expect to find any relationship.  The potential you are referring to involves breaking metallic bonds and ionizing the resulting atoms while conductivity involves electrons moving through the solid metal.  Copper's is -.34 and it is between gold and silver in conductivity.  Aluminum's is 1.66 and it is #4 behind gold in conductivity.